# Best Practice to create Factory in this case

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am using an API - [Tranquility](https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility) - to send messages to Druid.

Looking at the documentation and the example code, it looks like the sender is asynchronous and thread safe.

Here is the [Java Example](https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/metamx/tranquility/example/JavaExample.java) from the API.

My question is regarding design / pattern to apply when I have to create multiple senders with different configurations and being able to re-use them.

Senders are capable of sending over 100k messages per second, so I don't want to re-load the configs for sender.

My ideas is to create a factory of senders and get a specific sender based on the message type and send the messages.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answerable question (e.g. best practices) and may be more fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

However, I'm bored, so here is a stream of consciousness answer:

What you're describing sounds more like a "cache" or a "pool" than just a factory.  Is the logic essentially as follows (I don't know tranquility so this is just pseudocode)?

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    Sender sender = pool.findOrCreateSenderForMessageType(message.getType());
    sender.send(message);
}
```

If so then I would say that you have created a "sender pool" or a "sender cache".  Of course, this findOrCreateSenderForMessageType will need a reference to a factory...

```
public Sender pool.findOrCreateSenderForMessageType(MessageType type) {
    Sender sender = cache.findByType(type);
    if(sender == null) {
        sender = factory.createSender(type);
        cache.addSenderForType(sender, type);
    }
    return sender;
}
```

So I would say that you are using a factory and it seems valid to do so in context but at a bigger picture I would say you are using a cache/pool to solve the problem.  Although a pool is also a sort of factory.  The words used in design patterns are so vague.

It seems very similar in concept to a "[routing data source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html)".  So maybe you could describe it as:

`A message router which chooses an appropriate sender factory based on the message type`

And...

`A sender pool which caches created senders for reuse`

And...

`A sender factory which creates a sender for a given message type`

All three concepts could be represented as three different classes or all three could be combined in a single class.

For example, the router and cache could be combined so that the router has a `Map<MessageType, Sender>`.  This would be sufficient if you only ever needed one sender per message type.

Alternatively, if you might choose to use a different sender because a sender is currently busy or checked out (similar to how a thread pool or connection pool works) then you would probably want one or more classes dedicated to implementing the pool and you might end up with something like `Map<MessageType, SenderFactory>`